# Good guidelines on naming bool properties

Tags: .net, properties, naming-conventions

Generally if there is a property that gets/sets a value for state, I use "Is", like:

```
Visibility:
.IsVisible
```

But for properties that gets/sets actions, what is best to use? Like:

```
Casting shadows:
.CastShadows
```

Should I use:

```
.DoesCastShadows
```

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Much of the library uses something that would be like `.IsShadowCastingEnabled`.

For example, UIElement defines [IsInputMethodEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isinputmethodenabled.aspx) and [IsHitTestVisible](http://IsHitTestVisible).

The nice thing about this is that `IsXXX` makes it very clear that this is a boolean property.

Comment: Thanks, now I am split. I might go with your answer then. Btw when you said much of the library, you mean BCL or WPF or any other on the net?

Comment: @Joan: There's some differences - partly depending on age of the API.  For example, WCF often leaves the "Is" off, but still uses the rest of the basic concept...

Answer (score 5):

I think `CastsShadows` would work. Notice `s` after `Cast`. It's parallel with `Is` in that both start with singular verbs (and `Does` sounds rather tacky).

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to use "Is" for read-only properties; I'd probably use something like "EnableShadows" as a property.  It may not be immediately obvious from the name that it's a property rather than a method, but when reading code it should be obvious, and when writing code Intellisense should indicate that it's a property.  Further, if one tries to use EnableShadows as a method, the compiler should complain.

Comment: Some properties are behave like fields which cause things to happen when written, but will generally read the last thing written.  Others reflect some attribute of the object which will be controlled by something other than writes to the property.  Do you have any naming convention to distinguish them?

Comment: Do you mean whether something is calculated on the fly vs returned by a backing field vs properties that have no backing fields (defined by the programmer)? In that case, no I still don't use different names. I have properties like vector3.Length which is calculated on the fly.

Comment: I tend to view attributes in three groups: those which primarily change as a result of direct actions to the properties themselves, and those which can be changed by direct action to them but may also change externally, and calculated properties.  For the former type, I like read/write properties; for the last two types either read-only properties or getter methods (depending upon the work involved in retrieving the value), and for the middle one, setter methods.  It would be nice to distinguish the types via naming, but only in the case of booleans does a clean way come to mind ("Is")

Comment: @Joan Venge: (see above, plus...) I'm not sure exactly what criterion would define whether I feel a property should have an "Is".  Some things "feel" like they should and some don't.  A significant factor would probably be the nature of when the property is apt to change.  If some boolean property of an object is apt to spontaneously change as a result of actions to other objects or other events in the system, I'll be more inclined to want to "Is" the name (e.g. an "IsReady" property of a communications object to indicate it's ready for the program to give it data).